# how to check if selected text is inside two lines of text

Tags: javascript, html

We have text in the document and part of the text was selected by user with mouse like:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa****aaaa   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  aaaaaaa
a aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa****aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa
```

How can I check if selection is only in one line or in both?

html structure is like:

```
<div>
   <span> aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaa <span> selectedt text </span> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: That sounds difficult, as the text may have wrapped. Technically it's still on the same line, but visually it has wrapped.

Comment: In the end, you're just selecting text. Unless there is formatting contained within the selection, it's impossible I would think.

Comment: and if the selected text is inside <span> ?

Comment: is it just wrapped or there is a physical line break between 2 lines?

Comment: just wrapped with <span> tag(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know exactly what you are going for, but maybe this could help;

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html

Under section 'relatedTarget, fromElement, toElement' --> when you give the span elements an id, you could check from which element you started, and in which you ended. Hereby knowing if there was a cross in elements.

I do not think that it's possible to know exactly on which line (on screen) the user starts ends, because of text wrapping, resolution, screen size, font size etc.

Answer (score 1):

That all depends on the size of the users screen/window size

Answer (score 1):

An idea could be to momentarily span one character with a force-layout tag, a `span` with `position:relative`, check the height. Then compare it with the entire selections height, retrieved the same way.